# Python pandas "no module named format"

Tags: python, pandas, import, module

I have an error with Python 2.7.12 (Anaconda 4.1.1 64bit) when I try to run :

```
import pandas.core.format
```

It gives me:

> "No module named format"

I have pandas package installed and it is working fine with another computer. How to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been moved to `pandas.formats` in Pandas 0.18.1

so try this instead:

```
import pandas.formats.format
```

you can also do it version independent:

```
try:
    import pandas.formats.format
except ImportError:
    import pandas.core.format
```